# ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE SET fails with duplicate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
INSERT INTO loger(state, id, event_timestamp, other_event_timestamp)
VALUES 
   (1, 12, '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z'),
   (1, 12, '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z') 
    ON CONFLICT(id, event_timestamp) DO UPDATE SET state = excluded.state
```

During execution it fails with error:

```
ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
```

p.s. these data comes outside, so I should pass it to query as is.

Comment: Well, the error message tells you what you need to know: make sure you have no duplicates in the input data.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is pretty clear.  The `ON CONFLICT` clause refers to rows already in the table.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> INSERT with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause is a “deterministic” statement. This means that the command will not be allowed to affect any single existing row more than once; a cardinality violation error will be raised when this situation arises. **Rows proposed for insertion should not duplicate each other in terms of attributes constrained by an arbiter index or constraint.**

(I added the highlighting.)

You can reduce this to one row with some manipulation in the query.  For instance, the following inserts one arbitrary row:

```
INSERT INTO loger (state, id, event_timestamp, other_event_timestamp)
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, event_timestamp) state, id, event_timestamp, other_event_timestamp
    FROM (VALUES (1, 12, '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z'),
                 (1, 12, '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-01T19:00:00.000Z') 
         ) v(state, id, event_timestamp, other_event_timestamp)
    ORDER BY id, event_timestamp
    ON CONFLICT(id, event_timestamp) DO UPDATE SET state = excluded.state;
```

You can also structure your code as two separate `INSERT`s.

Comment: Where do `pounds` fits here ?

Comment: You mean `state = excluded.state` ?

Comment: @Niloct . . .  I certainly didn't rewrite the `SET` clause.  I think the OP changed the logic in the first five minutes.